# Huge ASPState database log

Tags: sql-server, logs

We're using SqlServer to store users session state of our webapps. We've recently noticed the ASPState.log_ldf file has reached 50GB.

Is it safe to put the web apps down and then drop and recreate the ASPState DB? I don't see the point of having backups of this DB so we would also set *simple recovery mode* in order to avoid this problem in the future and spare storage space.

Comment: If there is no need to recreate the aspstate database there is no need to shut down the web apps.

Answer (score 2):

Set Simple and shrink the .ldf without having to re-create...I've done it many times over the years, although its been awhile